# Use aggregation metric as a filter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a database containing logs about script runs. Some of these logs have StartTime and EndTime fields.

For each kind of scripts (id), I would like to query for those that have the above mentioned fields, and their run time (EndTime - StartTime) is beyond the 97.7 percentile of their kind (id).

I managed to return the duration corresponding to the 97.7th percentile for each script id with the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          { "exists": { "field": "StartTime"} },
          { "exists": { "field": "EndTime"} }
        ]
      } 
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "script_run_percentiles": {
      "terms": {
        "field":"ID"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "duration_percentiles": {
          "percentiles": {
            "script": "doc['EndTime'] - doc['StartTime']",
            "percents": ["97.7"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

How can I extend this query to return those script runs that are above this percentile? I think this have to be done using a filter, but I'm wondering if metrics can be filtered upon?

Comment: Currently, the duration percentiles aggregation will return all script id types that have start and end times, right? a percentile aggregation of a collection of documents will always way at least 1 document in the filtered range.  Are you trying to get the list of documents for each script type (ID) that are in that 97.7 - 100 range?

Comment: Yes it is, however I am currently using search_type=count , so only the aggregation results are returned, without fetching the documents. And yes,  your second question is basically what I want to achieve. I want to filter my aggregation to these documents (between 97.7 - 100), and sort by e.g. Endtime, only showing the top n. This way I will have the latest, most outstanding script_runs of their kind (id). The first thing that blocked me is using the metric to filter my documents, that's why i targeted my question at this.

Comment: You are trying to do the equivalent of a SQL Having statement. This is not currently supported by elasticsearch. There is not a way to filter a query by the results of an aggregation. Your best bet would be to load the script types, start/end time and the individual log id and then calculate the percentiles on your own.

Comment: How I feared to get this answer. Im going to end up writing an layer in a general programming language that creates multiple queries to solve this need. I hoped to get this done with the Query DSL. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your effort.